# MySQL order by '!columnName' is not equals to 'desc'

Tags: mysql, database

Can anyone explain me a difference between this two screenshots, like how actually it works? If you have ever tried.

1. Order by DESC is giving result like :

[image: order by descending]

2. Order by !column name , is also an example like order by desc but in a different ways.
   [image: order by !column name]

Comment: Down voter have you tried this?

Comment: `NOT` or `!` is a Boolean operator which is very clear from the MySQL documentation.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html#operator_not  Is it unclear to you that you are asking why there's a difference between integer and boolean?  "How does `ORDER BY` work?" is a very broad question, and your question is obfuscated and overlong for the subject matter.  For one thing screenshots should almost never be necessary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOT operator returns 1 or 0. So if you use !value1 then you get number of 0's and 1's and since you do not have another column in the ORDER BY, the order of the rows within the sets (1's and 0's) is not defined.

`ORDER BY value1 DESC` on the other hand orders rows in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help you "see" what happen (slaakso already gave you the answer), you can make some "experiment" starting with:

```
SELECT A, !A AS B FROM (
select 'A' AS A UNION SELECT 'C' AS A UNION SELECT 'B'  UNION SELECT 1  UNION SELECT 0 ) X
ORDER BY !A
```

Output:

```
    A   B
1   1   0
2   B   1
3   A   1
4   0   1
5   C   1
```